# How to write increase day helper in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, refactoring, helper

I have following helper which should puts day in words depends on number:

```
def day_in_words(number)
    case number
    when 0
      "Sunday"
    when 1
      "Monday"
    when 2
      "Tuesday"
    when 3
      "Wednesday"
    when 4
      "Thursday"
    when 5
      "Friday"
    when 6
      "Saturday"
    when 7
      "Sunday"
    when 8
      "Monday"
    when 9
      "Tuesday"
    when 10
      "Wednesday"
    when 11
      "Thursday"
    ...
    when 16
      "Sunday"
    when 17
      "Monday"
    when 18
      "Tuesday"
    when 19
      "Wednesday"
    when 20
      "Thursday"
    when 21
      "Friday"
    else
      "Unknown Day"
    end
  end
```

How to refactor that helper?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Have you tried this maybe ->

```
Date::DAYNAMES[number%7]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
def day_in_words(number)
  return "Unknown Day" if number > 20
  %w[sun mon tue wed thu fri sat].cycle(3).to_a[number]
end
```

Answer (score 0):

First thing that comes to mind is simply to use modulo 7 as the index to an array of the names of days:

```
def day_in_words(number)
  return ['Sun','Mon','Tue','Wed','Thurs','Fri','Sat'][number % 7]
end
```